# Check if google account has been verified by phone

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-plus-signin

I want to make login with google in my android application but I want to let do this only using google accounts that has been verified by phone (via voice or sms)

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/63950?hl=en

Is there any way to check through API if google account has been verified by phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that isn't possible. If you're concerned about account creation abuse, Google has top notch abuse team that is on top of spammers, fake accounts and other abuse related account creations. That is one of the reasons to use a social auth provider like Google in that you don't have to provide that abuse checking on your own.

Comment: so there is no need to check?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?